# How do I compare array value to the next value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am wanting to compare the next value in the array with my current value. If you look at my code I think you will see what I am trying to do but to explain I need only one picture to show if $row[2] is the same on the next loop thru.

My error start at // ERROR HERE in if Statement in the code below.

I am sure there is a simple solution to this but I don't know the proper name and could not find it in my searches.
-Disclaimer I am still an newbie at this please forgive me.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($connection)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// create query
$query = "SELECT * FROM 1098";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<center>";

        // ERROR HERE in if Statement
        $nextrow = 1 + $row;
        if ( $row[2] <> $nextrow[2]){

            if ( $row[6] == "kit"){
                $img ='<img style="width: 700px; height: 800px;" alt="Picture Not Found" src=" ';
                $file = substr($row[2], -3);
                $filepath='files/'.$row[6].'/'.$file.'_files/image001.png">';
                echo $img.$filepath;
            }
            else
            {
                $img ='<img style="width: 700px; height: 280px;" alt="Picture Not Found" src=" ';
                $filepath='files/'.$row[6].'/'.$row[2].'_files/image001.png">';
                echo $img.$filepath ;
            }
        }
        echo  "</center>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$nextrow = 1 + $row` doesn't make sense. That would be attempting to add an integer to a database record, i.e. `1 + array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')`.

If you simply want to compare the current record with the previous record (on all loops after the first one) how about something like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  print '<center>';

  // If there is no previous record set (first record) or if the 2nd value is different.
  if (!isset($prev_record) || $prev_record[2] != $row[2]) {
    // ...        
  }

  print '</center>';

  // Assign the current row to a variable so that it's available on the next run.
  $prev_record = $row;
}
```

**Edit** – here's an example of how you can get all records into a single array and then play with them:

```
$records = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  $records[] = $row;
}

foreach ($records as $i => $record) {
  $record; // current record
  $records[$i-1]; // last record
  $records[$i+1]; // next record
}
```

I would recommend splitting your data up into multiple tables, though, and using a cleaner approach.

Comment: I knew the $nextrow = 1 + $row was wrong, I thought it would a easy way to kinda explain what it was trying to do. I have data from the database I want to display above the picture and not below it.

Comment: Gotcha. Does my example code make sense and help solve the problem? Or are you really trying to display the next row's data in the current set of markup? Can you explain what kind of final result you're looking for?

Comment: I think yours code might work if I want the picture on top. Right now my working code display data the picture. Some items have 2 rows we are recording data in (each row in the database represent a characteristic of the part ie width or hole size) , some rows just require ais a visual with a picture  displaying the part. the pictures are not in the database they are stored on the server with $row[2] contains the part code

Comment: It sounds like you are storing different data models in the same table. I would try and separate those into different tables. But to do what you're looking for, you'd need all records in a single array so that you can play with them in your loop. Ultimately it will be a bit messy, but it's certainly doable. I'll throw an example in my answer.

Comment: In short if I put your code on the second picture the data will still be split between the first to pictures I think ?? maybe i am thinking wrong.. open to thoughts if i am. In the code above I cutout where I'm displaying the data -

Comment: Give an example of 2 records from your database, and an example of what you want the final complete markup to be.

Comment: I get Undefined offset  at $records[$i-1]; // last record and $records[$i+1]; // next record ?

Comment: Yeah, when you're on the first record there is no "previous" record. Likewise, when you're on the last record there is no "next" record.

Answer (score 0):

$nextrow = 1 + $row;
Given $row is a row, this is not doing what you think it is.

If you want the nextrow from the query you have to fetch it.

If you can reverse your logic to use previous row , you could preserve that and compare it to the current row.

You could read them all into an array first, but on a big result set that would be expensive....

You could do two fetches, one to current row, one to next row,

And then add a lot of logic to deal with the first and last, and making current = next and fetching the next next :(

Or you could rework the query so it returned the data you need in one row.

You definitely can't do what you are trying to do though. There is no next row until you fetch. $row is an array of columns, there is no rows as in an array of rows.

Comment: How do I fetch the next row only to compare current row, then re-fetch it to display data and the picture for that data?   The most data in this table at one time could be 5 - 10 rows before they are moved to achieve table.

Comment: You can't refetch as far as I'm aware , you can only re-query and start from the first row again, which would be inefficient and more than likely buggy.  If its only 5 - 10 rows. Just loop through and put them in a local array, then drive your output from the array. Be easier that sorting the query out. Note it is a bodge you can get away because the amount of data involved is so small.